# Expo: disable yellow warnings only in console

Tags: react-native, expo

I get a lot of warnings only in the Expo command line and, after having looked around a lot, has not found any way to hide them:

I've tried with the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import Setup from "./src/boot/setup";
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Require cycle']);
console.disableYellowBox = true;
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Setup />;
  }
}
```

but with no success

[image]

Comment: As far as I am aware YellowBox.ignoreWarnings will **only** disable the warning on the device, so you will always get the warnings in the console. You could also fix the warnings and import Expo as they suggest.

Comment: @Andrew I don't have that much control over the warnings, in my code I'm importing Expo normally, I get tons of warnings from modules

Comment: There’s nothing stopping you making pull requests on those dependencies to fix the errors.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, there is actually a ticket on Native base for that. In the end this was an Expo issue, they removed the warnings. Still don't know why YellowBox wasn't hiding them

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me.  From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799037/1615978).

```js
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Asyncstorage: ...']); // Ignore log notification by message
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(); //Ignore all log notifications
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue in the end was fixed in Expo 31.0.3. I had a fixed dependency on Expo 31.0.0, so updating to the latest version resolved the Warnings.