# How to suppress a specific warning in expo

Tags: react-native, expo, warnings

I am getting below warning

```
AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

[image]

How can I suppress it?

I have tried the below method(placed below lines in `app.js`) but none are working.

```js
import { LogBox } from 'react-native'

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` instead of `react-native`. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage'])
```

```js
import { LogBox } from 'react-native'

LogBox.ignoreLogs(["Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage"])
```

Can anyone help me to suppress it?

Answer (score 3):

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Asyncstorage: ...']); // Ignore log notification by message
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(); //Ignore all log notifications
```

Comment: this doesn't work on current version of expo, just does nothing

Answer (score -1):

Its a warning. Do not suppress it. I guess you are using Async storage from 'react-native' package. Instead install `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` and use it from here.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not triggering from my code. It is triggered from `node_modules`. How can I handle it?

Comment: react-native is in node_modules. It used to expose AsyncStorage but it was moved out of react native core. It is in the warning. This is why you should install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage as a dependancy and import AsyncStorage from there and not from react-native.